# How do stop/signal mq_receive() from receiving message?

Tags: c++, multithreading, message-queue

So I am trying to implement a multi-threaded Message Queue in C++ using [`mq_open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html).

So in my main, I have something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>

#include "ReaderQueue.h"
Message message;
ReadQueue reader(QUEUE_NAME,10,sizeof(message));
atomic_bool running(true);

void exitHandler(int dummy) {
    running = false;
}

void receive (ReadQueue* reader){
    while (running)
    {
        if(reader->reciveMessage(&message)){
            cout<<message.payload<<endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT, exitHandler);
    thread threads[1];
    for(thread& t : threads){
        t = thread(receive,&reader);
    }
    for(thread& t : threads){
        t.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And in my ReadQueue:

```
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <atomic>

struct Message {
    uint8_t type;
    uint64_t send_t;
    char payload[112];
};

class ReadQueue{
public:
    ReadQueue(string queueName,long maxSize,long msgSize){
        this->queueName = queueName;
        attr.mq_flags = 0;
        attr.mq_maxmsg = maxSize;
        attr.mq_msgsize = msgSize;
        attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

        mq = mq_open(queueName.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0644, &attr);
    }

    void closeReadering(){
        mq_close(mq);
    }

    ~ReadQueue(){
        mq_unlink(queueName.c_str());
    }

    bool reciveMessage(Message* message){
        bytes = mq_receive(mq,(char*)message,sizeof(*message),NULL);
        return bytes >= 0;
    }
private:
    mqd_t mq;
    ssize_t bytes;
    struct mq_attr attr;
    string queueName;
};
```

Right now, the problem is when I do Ctrl+C, it calls exitHandler, but its still stuck in the thread.
This is because in my reciveMessage(), the mq_receive() is still looking for messages. How do I send a signal to stop this?

Comment: Please turn that into a [mcve] so we can compile it without making any changes to the code.

Comment: Sorry, I added more.

Comment: It looks like you should use [`mq_notify`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_notify.3.html). I still can't copy your program and compile it without making any changes to the code though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code is stuck here:

> reader->reciveMessage(&message)

Check the receiveMessage code of Reader it must not be a blocking call.

Comment: Yea, I put the code for receiveMessage at the bottom. But, from man page of [mq_receive()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_receive), it says "mq_receive() blocks until a message becomes available, or the call is interrupted by a signal handler". I was wondering how do I send that signal.

Comment: @Dharshan You use [`std::raise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/raise) to send a signal to the program itself - but that won't help. You already get the signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a cancellation request to the required thread to terminate using `pthread_cancel`(linux) function like this.

```
pthread_cancel(thread1.native_handle());
```

Note: This cancellation request has to be sent after `exit_handler` function sets `running` flag to `false`.